# Static assert in template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, static-assert

I would like to ask if it is possible to insert static assert into template parameters.

Let´s say I want to create class `StaticArray<T,N>` and I want to make it impossible for users to instantiate this class with size equal to 0. Is there any way to insert something like `static_assert(N != 0, "error message")` into my class?

Comment: You probably want to assert that the size is _greater_ than zero, not inequal.

Answer (score 6):

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class StaticArray
{
    static_assert(N != 0, "error message");
};
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9db972b0ece5dcd)